Java's IllegalException (request object has been recycled) being triggered in asynchronous process
My codebase has a central event which is suddenly logging errors. They're all the same, except for the class shown as the argument to the run() method.

2024-11-06 22:32:12,435 AuditService ERROR accounts.service.audit.AuditService run(ProfileChangeRequestDenied): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade

This code has been unchanged for several years, but is only now throwing these errors after our recent upgrade to Tomcat 9. Per my research it appears that Tomcat 9 has changed the default setting of org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES from false to true. I understand the issue, our code is trying to access a request which no longer exists. But this base class is being used everywhere, and the log entries only just started happening. Ideally I'd be able to implement a patch to give us time to work on a larger fix.
Here's the distilled version of the ServiceAccount class which appears to be what is causing the error. Via step debugging I've tracked it down to the servletRequest.getHeader call in the getUserAgent method, after which the log entry appears.
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public abstract class ServiceEvent {
    private final HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public ServiceEvent(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public String getUserAgent() {
        String userAgent = null;
        if (null != servletRequest) {
            userAgent = servletRequest.getHeader(USER_AGENT);
        }
        return (userAgent == null) ? UNKNOWN : userAgent;
    }

    public abstract String getDetails();
}

We have a script which sets environment variables for Tomcat, and I've tried setting the following line, but it doesn't appear to have any effect.
CATALINA_OPTS="-D-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=true ${CATALINA_OPTS}"

So, my questions are:

Is my hypothesis correct, and updating the RECYCLE_FACADES value should revert this behavior?
Am I doing the setting correctly?
Is there something else I'm leaving out?

Note that while I've been a software engineer for quite some time, I've only been using Java for about a year.

I finally tracked it down. Within my server.xml file I applied discardFacades="false" to the <Connector /> tag and it seems to have resolved the issue.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector
            discardFacades="false"
        />
    </Service>
</Server>


